# anonymous pipes in c with execlp

Tags: c, redirect, pipe

i have a homework for my university in which i must have a main process and 3 child processes. I must read an expression in the main process from the user and then pass it through an anonymous pipe at p1 process with redirection of standard input. Then i must modify it and pass it with another pipe to p2. Then the same thing happens with p3 with another pipe. Finally i must return the final expression from p3 to main process using another pipe. When i create p1,p2,p3 processes in the main process by calling fork, i use execlp to run the code of each of these process.

What i managed to do until now(apart from each process' logic which was really complicated), is to send the expression of the user from the main process to p1 process. Inside the code of p1 in the main process, i redirected to the input of the p1 to the read end of the first pipe and i successfully read the expression from main process.

My problem is with the other processes. I really got stuck on how to correctly redirect the inputs and outputs of each pipe to communicate with all processes. I really would appreciate any help here.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this EXAMPLE you can see the execlp() function and the fork() function:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
   pid_t pid;
   char *pathvar;
   char newpath[1000];

   pathvar = getenv("PATH");
   strcpy(newpath, pathvar);
   strcat(newpath, ":u/userid/bin");
   setenv("PATH", newpath);

   if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
      perror("fork error");
   else if (pid == 0) {
      execlp("newShell", "newShell", NULL);
      printf("Return not expected. Must be an execlp error.n");
   }
}
```

Here you can see how to make a pipe between two process:

```
/*
 “ls -R | grep <pat>” where <pat> is a pattern
 */

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
    int pipe1[2];
    int pid1;
    int pid2;
    char stringa[100];

    pipe(pipe1); // creo la pipe

    if((pid1=fork())==0)
    {
        close(pipe1[0]);
        dup2(pipe1[1],1);
        close(pipe1[1]);
        execlp("ls","ls","-R",NULL);
    }

    if((pid2=fork())==0)
    {
        close(pipe1[1]);
        dup2(pipe1[0],0);
        close(pipe1[0]);
        execlp("grep","grep",argv[1],NULL); 
    }

    close(pipe1[0]);
    close(pipe1[1]);
    waitpid(pid1,NULL,0);
    waitpid(pid2,NULL,0);
    exit(0);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The second example is more close to what i need. Here is my questions. Why in the second process you don't close the read end of the fd? And why close both read and write of pipe in the parent process?

Comment: An anonymous pipe is a communication channel that join two process with a common ancestor.
Each pipe has in and out access. each access has a file descriptor.
When a process has using a side of a pipe, you MUST close the file descriptor with a close().

Comment: I must close the side of pipe i used or the one i didn't use?

Comment: ok... i have written 3 examples: 
- the 1st is the edit of my answer (only one pipe);
- the 2nd (two pipe) --> https://gist.github.com/worm1988/9917849
- the 3rd (three pipe) --> https://gist.github.com/worm1988/9917868

I hope it is clear now ;)

Comment: It's much more clear now. Your example really helped me to understand when i should close each side of pipe. However i'm still having problem. I used 4 pipes and in each process, when i closed each side of pipes i didn't used and tried to pass a string from main process across each child process and then back to main process everything worked fine. When i used execlp to pass the string through my code for each process, nothing returned back to main process. In each process i read an expression using fgets and write it using printf. I redirect stdout of each process. Where is my problem?

Comment: Nevermind. I found my problem. It was inside the code of one of the process. I had one unnecessary printf. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

From your description I think you want to chain forking. E.g. instead of having main fork three times to create p1, p2 and p3, instead let main fork once to create p1, then let p1 fork once to create p2 which also forks once to create p3.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm new to processes and i would need a little more help. How exactly can i do what you suggest? Keep in mind that i must use execlp in each of the 3 child processes to execute the code of each process. Actually what i did right now, is to call fork 3 times and save the id of the process that created. Then inside the code of each process' code, before i call execlp, i redirect the inputs and outputs i want and close all pipes i don't use. But i'm not sure if i closed and redirected everything ok.